# Map en array no funciona en uno pero en otro si

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, bucles, map

Tengo este codigo para acceder a un array dentro de mi objeto

```
data.map((tem, key) => {
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      <h1>{tem.name}</h1>
      <p>{key}</p>
      <img src={tem.wikiPortraitUrlLarge} alt="" />
      {tem.techniques.map((tem, otra) => {
        return (
          <div key={otra}>
            <span> {tem.name}</span>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {tem.malisimo.map((tipos, mal) => {
        return (
          <div key={mal}>
            <span> {tipos.name}</span>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Todo funciona bien excepto por el `tem.malismo.map`, deberia funcionar ya que es igual al anterior `tem.techniques.map`

me arroja "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Ejemplo de los arrays :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías agregar una validación para que haga el map solo si malisimo tiene un valor, ’tem.malisimo && tem.malisimo.map‘

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pongo la validación pero me sigue arrojando el mismo error, eso significa que si la pasa pero sigue sin acceder al tipos.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu error ocurre porque la variable `data` es un `Object` en lugar de un `Array`. Esto lo estoy infiriendo de la imagen que publicaste. Si quieres utilizar la función `map` con un `Object` debes primero llamar a la función `entries` para obtener un arreglo de arreglos con el par llave valor del objeto. Por ejemplo:

```js
Object.entries(data).map((key, value) => ...);
```

Más información: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries

Nota: Si publicas la definición de la variable `data` te puedo seguir ayudando

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por comentar ya lo resolví, era un error con un dato, venia diferente. pero lo que me comentas si lo utilice y si sirve, pero pude entrar normalmente como map. Saludos.